# How to get facebook sponsored stories using API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any possible way to get sponsored stories in the facebook newsfeed using graph API or any facebook API's.
I am not getting suggested stories thorugh newsfeed API.

https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=AAA####

Comment: I dont think there is an api to get sponsored stories of users. Since Sponsored stories is a facebook ad platform and fb will show sponsored stories related to users. If you have ads-api access then may have some kind of access to sponsored stories.

Comment: checkout this URL https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/intro-sponsored-stories/

Comment: It is said, there are some option to preview the sponsored stories.Still it doesn't help to see as how it looks in the news feed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sponsored stories are created by advertisers but fb algorithm decides to whom it needs to be displayed.  So I believe, using Fb Ad Api advertisers can get some insights about their sponsored stories. Other then this, there is no way you can get sponsored stories from newsfeed.

**What is Sponsored Stories ?**

Sponsored Stories are built around user activity. Advertisers simply pay to highlight an action that users have already taken on the social network or within a Facebook-connected app. That action is shown to a user’s friends, either in the sidebar or in News Feed.

Advertisers do not have any creative control over these ad types because they are generated from an organic user action.

The most common Sponsored Stories are “Page Like” stories, but advertisers can sponsor check-ins, offer claims, Likes on individual posts, or any custom Open Graph action.

Companies can also sponsor stories about when users share links from their domain. For example, when a user posts an Amazon link on Facebook, Amazon pays to show that story to more of a user’s friends, as seen to the right.

The goal of Sponsored Stories to get more users to take the same action that a friend has. If a page wants Likes, it can show Page Like Sponsored Stories. If a retailer wants more users to claim an offer, it can show Offer Claimed Sponsored Stories. If a company wants more sweepstakes entries in its custom Open Graph app, it can create Sponsored Stories about users “entering a sweepstakes.”

Most Sponsored Stories can be created through the self-serve ad tool, Power Editor or API, however, Open Graph Sponsored Stories require advertisers to work with a third-party provider that has access to the API.

Checkout this [Original Source](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2013/01/11/understanding-the-difference-between-facebook-sponsored-stories-page-post-ads-promoted-posts-and-marketplace-ads/) for more details ( *Understanding the difference between Facebook Sponsored Stories, Page Post Ads, Promoted Posts and Marketplace Ads* )

I hope this helps !